# Is there a way to validate an Email (ex. The presence of an unsubscribe link) using SOAP API call?

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

Looking for a way to validate an email via SOAP API call before attempting to send.

From Marketing Cloud/Email Studio, users are able to Validate Email as described in this link:
https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/validate/

However, is there an equivalent SOAP API call that would give the same result?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if there's a standard method that you could call, but you could always use RegEx.

Perhaps [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/using_regular_expressions_to_validate_email_addresses.htm) could help.

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, I am not looking to validate an email address instead I am looking to validate the email template that will be used to send an email.